# Dell Latitude E6420 touchpad scrolling is temperamental

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, scrolling

I recently bought an old **Dell Latitude E6420** laptop for cheap. As it's not *very* powerful, I installed **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS** onto it to speed some it up somewhat. I have also wanted to properly use and learn Linux for a while so this was an opportunity to do that.

The scrolling on the trackpad works sometimes and other times not. I will be two-finger scrolling a window and all of a sudden my mouse pointer will fly off somewhere as if I have taken off a finger and I am just using it normally. I'm trying to diagnose if it is a hardware problem or a software problem; it's an old, second-hand laptop so maybe the trackpad has seem some wear and tear. Or maybe there are some drivers I am missing or something I need to fix in the settings maybe.

So what steps can I take to find eliminate software issues/solutions?

Thanks.

*Edit:* I'm coming back here to say that it was a hardware issue. The touchpad is just old and well used, I'm using a bluetooth mouse.

Comment: While inconvenient, an external mouse is very useful. I have here a very handy small Lenovo, where the trackpad once in a while wants to be very temperamental, and I have no idea of what to do to do it when it happens.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I was thinking of just doing that. I have a small bluetooth mouse that I could use with it, I may just do that.

Also, why did you edit my post?